# Windows 10 hosts file not resolving any domains

Tags: windows, dns, windows-10, virtualhost, hosts

I edited my hosts file to add a new local dev enviroment and ever since then it will not work, even without the new entry. I though the file must be corrupt so i made a new one, still no luck.

I have made sure the correct syntax is being used, correct encoding (ANSI also tried UTF-8), there is no .txt file extension, no strange characters (using show Characters on notepad++) I have even tried setting it as a system file to try and force windows to use it but that didn't work either.

Also i flushed the ipconfig dns, i have tried turning off the windows DNS service, rebooted.
It seems asif it is being completly ignored.

I've been on google most of the day and this has me stumped!

hosts file contains the following

```
127.0.0.1 ocommerce.test
127.0.0.1 www.ocommerce.test
```

that is it.

I have also tried

```
127.0.0.1 ocommerce.test www.ocommerce.test
```

and

```
127.0.0.1    ocommerce.test www.ocommerce.test
```

When pinging the domain i get "Ping request could not find host ocommerce.test. Please check the name and try again."

Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated.

EDIT:

If anyone else is struggling with this even after creating new files try copying this and adding your lines to the bottom. (this is what i copied, no idea why but it worked after that!)

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a ‘#’ symbol.
#
# For example:
#
# 102.54.94.97 rhino.acme.com # source server
# 38.25.63.10 x.acme.com # x client host
# localhost name resolution is handle within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
# ::1 localhost
```

Comment: Turn on show file extensions in Explorer and ensure your Hosts file doesn't have a ".txt" extension.  If it does, remove it.

Comment: @T.Heron Thanks but show extensions is on there, is no extension on the file, the file is named "hosts"

Comment: Ok, then copy a known good file over from another machine, and be sure to edit the new file only with the Windows built-in Notepad editor or with Notepad++ - not with anything else.

Comment: Thats done it, maybe some of the comments in the original hosts file are required? or the file was still corrupt even after creating multiple new ones. either way thankyou!

Comment: Let me make this into an answer, just be sure to accept, as it shows up as "Green" on people's searches for this type of problem in the future.

Comment: I just encountered a scenario on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter where the hosts file was being ignored until I made a dummy edit to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy a known good file over from another machine, and be sure to edit the new file only with the Windows built-in Notepad editor or with Notepad++ - not with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new text file and Copy the content of the hosts file into the new file.
Then remove the existing hosts file and rename the new file as hosts file (no extension needed).  This should resolve your problem